# Meteor deployment: Meteor requires Node v0.10.36 or later

Tags: node.js, meteor, amazon-ec2

When I try to deploy meteor build to EC2. meteor says  `Meteor requires Node v0.10.36 or later` but node version is `v0.13.0-pre`.

Here the steps I tried

```
$ tar -zxvf bundle.tgz
$ sudo npm install
$ PORT=81 export MONGO_URL='mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/dbname'
$ cd ../../
$ sudo node main.js
Meteor requires Node v0.10.36 or later.
```

**Note:** reason of port 81 is I already installed LAMP server.

Answer (score 0):

Meteor not even support Node v0.12 yet. https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/3666

Try revert to v0.10.38

Comment: If you don't mind may I know how to revert `v0.10.38`. `yum install nodejs` installs latest version

Comment: I tried both `v0.10.36` and `v0.10.38` same problem occurs

Comment: What "node -v" give you ?

Comment: `v0.10.36` I think bug in meteor

Comment: That's weird. Try run 'npm install && npm update' in your app path

Comment: Same problem. I tried by commenting version checker code in `programs/server/boot.js`. New error is `Error: /home/ec2-user/app/bundle/programs/server/npm/npm-bcrypt/node_modules/bcrypt/build/Release/bcrypt_lib.node: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32
`